# Not publish item after moving its workflow state through PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I am moving workflow state through Powershell script to approved state. However, it is not publishing that item in the web database.

Code:-

```
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item.__Workflow=$workflowId
$item."__Workflow state"=$workflowStateId
$item."__Default Workflow"=$workflowId
$item.Editing.EndEdit($false,$false)
```

Comment: Did you try manually changing this? Is it working? And did you check the raw value that the ID is updating of the desired workflow?

Comment: Are you using the proper code format using brackets? - `$item.Fields["__Workflow state"].Value = $workflowStateId`

Comment: @SumitBhatia, yes I have tried manually and it is working fine and checked its raw value as well and it is updating.

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat, I have tried your code and still it is not updating and showing in web databse .

Comment: @Nisha publishing means? after running the PowerShell, you are manually publishing the item and it's not going to web database?

Comment: I am trying to move workflow state to approved state through powershell script so it will show in web database , it is not working.

Comment: For that you have to publish item as well though powershall after updating workflow state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the Workflow State field does not trigger any workflow actions. You need to use the `WorkflowProvider` to get the workflow and move it to the desired state.

With SPE you can do this via the `Invoke-Workflow` command:

```
Invoke-Workflow -Path master:/path-to-your/item `
    -CommandName "The Name of the Command" -Comments "Automated"
```

This will change the state of the item and execute any workflow actions that are setup in your workflow.

Here is the documentation for [Invoke-Workflow](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/invoke-workflow)